# How can i do multiple stationary tests for multiple timeseries in a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following df:

```
head(vardata)
       Month repo Callrate  WPI GDP  FED    nse   usd
1 2001-04-01 9.00     7.49 5.41 4.6 4.50 1125.2 46.79
2 2001-05-01 8.75     8.03 5.60 4.6 4.00 1167.9 46.92
3 2001-06-01 8.50     7.24 5.30 4.6 3.75 1107.9 47.00
4 2001-07-01 8.50     7.19 5.23 5.3 3.75 1072.8 47.14
5 2001-08-01 8.50     6.94 5.41 5.3 3.50 1053.8 47.13
6 2001-09-01 8.50     7.30 4.52 5.3 3.00  913.9 47.65
```

I want to conduct Box.test, adf.test, and kpss.test for all the 7 var with following set of rules:

Say I set a significance level of 5%. Then the rules are:

1) For the Box.test, if p-value < 0.05 => stationary

2) For the adf.test, if p-value < 0.05 => stationary

3) For the kpss.test, if p-value > 0.05 => stationary (note change of inequality)

Individually i did the tests as:

```
Box.test(ts(df$repo),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  ts(df$repo)
X-squared = 1100, df = 20, p-value <2e-16

adf.test(ts(df$repo),alternative = "stationary")

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  ts(df$repo)
Dickey-Fuller = -2.7, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.3
alternative hypothesis: stationary

kpss.test(ts(df$repo))

    KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  ts(df$repo)
KPSS Level = 0.32, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.1

# to extract p values
Box.test(ts(df$repo),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value
adf.test(ts(df$repo),alternative = "stationary")$p.value
kpss.test(ts(df$repo))$p.value
```

This was done one at a time for all the variables.....

But I would like to do all these tests in one go for all the var & outputted in some sort of a data frame if possible maybe something like this:

```
   var         box.pvalue  box  adf.pvalue adf  kpss.pvalue kpss
   repo          0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   Callrate      0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   WPI           0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   GDP           0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   FED           0.51      FALSE   0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   nse           0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   usd           0.45      FALSE   0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
```

Where TRUE= series is stationary ; FALSE= series is NON-stationary

## update--- my attempt

stationarity tests for multiple time series

```
multi_stat_tests<- function(df){
  for(i in 1:dim(df)[2]){
    df_multi<-data.frame(var=names(df)[i],box.pvalue=Box.test(ts(df[,i]),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value,adf.pvalue=adf.test(ts(df[,i]),alternative = "stationary")$p.value,kpss.pvalue=kpss.test(ts(df[,i]))$p.value,
box=Box.test(ts(df[,i]),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value<0.05,
adf=adf.test(ts(df[,i]),alternative = "stationary")$p.value<0.05,
kpss=kpss.test(ts(df[,i]))$p.value>0.05
)
    return(df_multi)
  }
}

>multi_stat_tests(df[,2:8])

  var box.pvalue    adf.pvalue   kpss.pvalue  box   adf  kpss
1 repo          0     0.2859         0.1     TRUE  FALSE TRUE
```

Its just picking up only one var......its not iterating across all the variables...missing something here....HELP required!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return result in the first iteration of loop, that is why you only get result for the first variable. I think this achieves what you want.

```
multi_stat_tests<- function(df){
    p <- ncol(df)
    df_multi <- data.frame(var=names(df),
                           box.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) Box.test(ts(v),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value),
                           adf.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) adf.test(ts(v),alternative = "stationary")$p.value),
                           kpss.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) kpss.test(ts(v))$p.value)
                           )
    df_multi$box <- df_multi$box.pvalue < 0.05
    df_multi$adf <- df_multi$adf.pvalue < 0.05
    df_multi$kpss <- df_multi$kpss.pvalue > 0.05
    df_multi
}
```

Addition:

If you don't want to have row names,

```
multi_stat_tests<- function(df){
    p <- ncol(df)
    df_multi <- data.frame(var=names(df),
                           box.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) Box.test(ts(v),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value),
                           adf.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) adf.test(ts(v),alternative = "stationary")$p.value),
                           kpss.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) kpss.test(ts(v))$p.value)
                           )
    df_multi$box <- df_multi$box.pvalue < 0.05
    df_multi$adf <- df_multi$adf.pvalue < 0.05
    df_multi$kpss <- df_multi$kpss.pvalue > 0.05
    row.names(df_multi) <- c()
    df_multi
}
```

Comment: @Consistency.......awesme....learnt smethng new....just a small issue ..the output has row names....i had to remove it separately..can it be incorporated in the loop......

Comment: @Nishant If you don't want to have row names, you can do something like `r <- multi_stat_tests(df); row.names(r) <- c()` or just add some line in the function like `row.names(df_multi) <- c()` before the final line `df_multi` which returns result.